# Swift Firebase Database Error Handling

Tags: swift, firebase, error-handling, firebase-realtime-database

I have the code snippet below and if an error occurs, I want to display a label with the error message and then a retry button. However when a error occurs, the error is printed to the logs, but label and button are not displayed. Am I missing something?

```
            user_ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "userdetails")

            self.user_ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                if !snapshot.exists() { return }
                let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

                if let temp_usertype = snapshotValue?["usertype"] as? String {
                    usertype = temp_usertype
                }

                self.user_ref.removeAllObservers()

                self.close()
            })
            {(error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)

                self.lblMessage.text = "\(error.localizedDescription)"
                self.btnRetry.isEnabled = true
                self.btnRetry.alpha = 1.0
                return
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Changes to the UI need to be processed on the main thread. You'll need to place that code into a Async.Main call like this :

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

}
```

Sometimes trying to call the main thread and updating the UI in a closure causes crashes so it would be better if you passed the error object through a completion block and when it reaches the end function, call a function that launches an alert that displays the error message as the title and the code as the message (or visa versa) and has a close button.

Comment: If you have questions about how that works, take a look at this page. https://github.com/JZDesign/OnTheMap/blob/master/OnTheMap/Client.swift